# Can a partial specialization refer to sizeof(T) in the specialization's argument list?

Tags: c++

Look at this simple code ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/GJLSbQ)):

```
template <typename, int>
struct Foo;

template <typename T>
struct Foo<T, (int)sizeof(T)>;
```

Clang compiles it, while gcc doesn't:

```
error: template argument '(int)(sizeof (T))' involves template parameter(s)
    struct Foo<T, (int)sizeof(T)>;
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Which compiler is correct and why?

Comment: MSVC gives these errors: Error C2755 'Foo<T,sizeof(T)>': non-type parameter of a partial specialization must be a simple identifier, and Error C2753 'Foo<T,sizeof(T)>': partial specialization cannot match argument list for primary template

Comment: In fact, it depends of "standard".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/temp.class.spec#8.1

> A partially specialized non-type argument expression shall not involve a template parameter of the partial specialization except when the argument expression is a simple identifier.

`sizeof(T)` is not a simple identifier.

So gcc is right.

Possible work around, if appropriate, is to replace non-type template parameter by a type (wrapping the constant):

```
template <typename, typename Size>
struct Foo;

template <typename T>
struct Foo<T, std::integral_constant<int, (int)sizeof(T)>>;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/nmHsjZ)

More recent version [temp.class.spec#match-3](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.class.spec#match-3) (after [CWG1315](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1315)) allows it:

> If the template arguments of a partial specialization cannot be deduced because of the structure of its template-parameter-list and the template-id, the program is ill-formed. [ Example:
>
> ```
> template <int I, int J> struct A {};
> template <int I> struct A<I+5, I*2> {};     // error
>
> template <int I> struct A<I, I> {};         // OK
>
> template <int I, int J, int K> struct B {};
> template <int I> struct B<I, I*2, 2> {};    // OK
> ```
>
> — end example ]

So clang is right.

Comment: I don't see how the workaround is valid: it still involves a template parameter of the partial specialization `T`

Comment: It is no longer a non-type argument, but a type argument... Not sure that that rule was useful indeed when similar thing with type is allowed. `Foo<I+2, I*5>` could be forbidden as with type as I is non deducible (if it was the rational).

Comment: @bolov: And it was indeed fixed :) (I was looking in a too old draft).